# Selenium with Kendo UI

Tags: selenium, kendo-ui

We are using Kendo UI for our buttons and textbox. It is causing issues for selenium. If user test manually then steps are>> they drag their mouse over to the text box, the text box is highlighted and the user clicks on the textbox. Then the cursor starts to show up and the user can type in.

As for selenium 'driver.findElement' is able to find the textbox but not able to get a cursor. I tried textbox.click and mouse event too,

Comment: we can't help with a very broad question. Please be specific, also you need to add your code, Html, screen shot or something that we can look into

Comment: Have you tried using `Actions` to hover before setting the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set value of element using the `executeScript` method:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'yourValue')");
```

EDIT:

But as @JeffC already mentioned, it is not a "clear" solution. The better one you can see below.

As you can see [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index) the text box is working as following:

1. you have to click on the first input via this xPath: `//ul[@id = 'fieldlist']/li[1]/label/span/span/input[1]`

[image]

it is this input field:

[image]

2. Before clicking on first input the second input

[image]

had `display:none`. And now it has `display:inline-block`, so we can perform `sendKeys()` action on this(second) element via this xPath `//ul[@id = 'fieldlist']/li[1]/label/span/span/input[2]`.

The same thing you can do in your case.

PS in the code it would be like this:

```
WebElement firstInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id = 'fieldlist']/li[1]/label/span/span/input[1]")); 
firstInput.click();

new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@id = 'fieldlist']/li[1]/label/span/span/input[2]")); // waits until second input becomes visible

WebElement secondInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id = 'fieldlist']/li[1]/label/span/span/input[2]")); 
secondInput.sendKeys("55");
```

Comment: Using JS to shortcut around UI actions can cause issues with the page/site. The site is built expecting certain actions to be performed. When you directly assign a value to a field using JS, you are going around those site protections, etc. No user is going to run JS to insert text into a field. Using JS will not simulate real user actions.

Comment: @krishna I have added another suggestion to my answer. Please have a look on it and let me know if it helped you

Comment: @andrei-suvorkov- It works perfectly- it was because of "style="display: inline-block;"

Comment: @Krishna if you are satisfied with my help, please mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button